# How to get row numbers for elements of XML, using XSLT at mutiple complex and repetitive leves?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an input as follows :

```
<root>
    <image>
        <imag1 ></imag1>
        <imag1 ></imag1>
        <imag2 ></imag2>
    <imageLink>
        <url colNumber="1">aa</url>
        <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
        <languageCode colNumber="3">en</languageCode>
        <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
    </imageLink>
    <imageLink>
        <url colNumber="1">bb</url>
        <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
        <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
        <commTest>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fssdr</languageCode>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fr</languageCode>
            <dummy colNumber="5">DDDUMM</dummy>
        </commTest>
        <commTest>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
            <dummy colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
        </commTest>
    </imageLink>
    <changedName>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
            <dummy colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
        </changedName>
        <changedName>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
            <languageCode colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
            <dummy colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
        </changedName>
    </image>
</root>
```

And my output required is as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image rowNum="1">
   <imag1 rowNum="1"/>
   <imag1 rowNum="2"/>
   <imag2 rowNum="1"/>
   <imageLink rowNum="1">
      <url rowNum="1" colNumber="1">aa</url>
      <imageTypeCode rowNum="1" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="1" colNumber="3">en</languageCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="2" colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
   </imageLink>
   <imageLink rowNum="3">
      <url rowNum="3" colNumber="1">bb</url>
      <imageTypeCode rowNum="3" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="3" colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
      <commTest rowNum="3">
         <languageCode rowNum="3" colNumber="4">fssdr</languageCode>
         <languageCode rowNum="4" colNumber="4">fr</languageCode>
         <dummy rowNum="3" colNumber="5">DDDUMM</dummy>
      </commTest>
      <commTest rowNum="5">
         <languageCode rowNum="5" colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
         <languageCode rowNum="6" colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
         <dummy rowNum="5" colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
      </commTest>
   </imageLink>
   <changedName rowNum="1">
      <languageCode rowNum="1" colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="2" colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
      <dummy rowNum="1" colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
   </changedName>
   <changedName rowNum="3">
      <languageCode rowNum="3" colNumber="4">fd777r</languageCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="4" colNumber="4">fr777</languageCode>
      <dummy rowNum="3" colNumber="5">DDD777UMM</dummy>
   </changedName>
</image>
```

this process happens in multiple levels of element complexity, these row numbers are assigned so that it enters into an excel sheet in the form of rows and columns

can anyone please assist me??

Comment: Have you tried any? what is the logic behind assigning `rowNum`?

Comment: Post your XSLT!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get row numbers for elements of XML, using XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606461/how-to-get-row-numbers-for-elements-of-xml-using-xslt)

Comment: I have stared at this for a while, and I cannot see any logic to your assignment of row numbers to particular elements.

Comment: whenever there is change in the main parent element the the row number resets from 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XSLT, based on numbering in *any* mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- To omit root node -->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="image"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- All other elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- Depth level -->
        <xsl:variable name="lvl" select="count(ancestor::*) - 1"/>
        <!-- Name of the current node -->
        <xsl:variable name="currName" select="name()"/>
        <!-- Name of the ancestor for numeration -->
        <xsl:variable name="ancName">
            <!-- Children of image - just 'image' -->
            <xsl:if test="$lvl &lt;= 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="'image'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- "Deeper" descendants - one level deeper -->
            <xsl:if test="$lvl &gt; 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[$lvl - 1]/name()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- Create element with current name -->
        <xsl:element name="{$currName}">
            <!-- Set rowNum -->
            <xsl:attribute name="rowNum">
                <xsl:number level="any" from="*[name()=$ancName]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- Process inner content -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The numeration is a bit diffrent from your sample, but:

1. From your required output sample I see that direct children of *image*
   with the same name get consecutive numbers in the whole output.
2. As you stated in the comment starting with *whenever there is change...*,
   *rowNum*s for all descendants of direct children of image should get numbers from 1 (separate counting within groups of nodes with the same name).